# Finding limit points of $\{2^n \sqrt 2\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find limit points of $\{2^n \sqrt 2\}$, where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part  function? This is  a subsequence of   the sequence $\{\sqrt n\}$ for which we know the set of limit points.  However, it is not clear to me if  $\{2^n \sqrt 2\}$ converge or has several limit points.

Comment: Is this a homework question? It is not at the appropriate level for mathoverflow.

Comment: I do not know whether the answer is known. For example, a similar question, the equirepartition modulo 1 of $((3/2)^n)_{n \ge 0}$ is an open question (to my knowledge). Indicating where the questions come from would be useful: is it related to a question in research or does it come from an exercise?

Comment: It is related to a research question. I was reading a survey on some Ramanujan's  diophantine equations (see e.g. pp. 12-14 in "The problems submitted by Ramanujan to the indian mathematical society", and I though that some of them can be related to the posted question!

Comment: @Anthony Quas: Your comment indicates that you know the answer. Would you please share  your knowledge with the community. Thank you.

Comment: It is suspected (but not proved) that $\sqrt{2}$ is normal in all bases.  This would imply that $\{2^n \sqrt{2}\}$ has every element of $[0,1]$ as limit point.  The reason is that the binary expansion for $\{2a\}$ is obtained as the left shift of the binary expansion of $\{a\}$.

Comment: It is certainly known that there is more than one limit point. Write out the base 2 expansion of $\sqrt2$. As @geraldedgar says, Doubling and taking the fractional part is equivalent to shifting the binary expansion left and truncating the first term. Since $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, the binary expansion is not periodic. It follows that the set of limit points is infinite.

Comment: Here is the related question on SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573684/at-least-one-even-number-among-lfloor-2n-sqrt2-rfloor-lfloor-2n1. Not an answer to the question but there are some estimates for number of ones and zeroes in the binary expression of $\sqrt{2}$.